# lodash sorting array by discountPrice if discount is active

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm looking for a way (preferably lodash) to sort the games by discountPrice if disountActive is true, else by price.

```
const { sortBy } = require('lodash');

const games = [
  { name: 'wow', price: 10, discountActive: false, discountPrice: 9 },
  { name: 'doom', price: 5, discountActive: true, discoutPrice: 4 },
  { name: 'mk', price: 15, discountActive: false, discountPrice: 11 },
  { name: 'aoe', price: 20, discountActive: true, discountPrice: 10 },
];

const sorted = sortBy(games, [function (game) {
  if (game.discountActive) {
    return game.discountPrice;
  } else {
    return game.price;
  }
}]);
```

This is the result i'm looking for.

```
  { name: 'doom', price: 5, discountActive: true, discoutPrice: 4 },
  { name: 'wow', price: 10, discountActive: false, discountPrice: 9 },
  { name: 'aoe', price: 20, discountActive: true, discountPrice: 10 },
  { name: 'mk', price: 15, discountActive: false, discountPrice: 11 },
```

Comment: Doesn't your code work as you want?

Comment: I don't understand why'd you want to do that? According to the current format of the array, you can either sort it by discount price or price. If you still want to sort, I'd suggest to separate array into two, one with `discountActive: true` and other with `discountActive: false` and then sort accordingly.

Comment: @riazosama lodash can deal with it, so why not to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sort`. Create a custom function which returns the price value based on `discountActive`. Then subtract the value for `a` and `b` in the `comapreFunction` to sort them in ascending order

```js
const games = [{name:'wow',price:10,discountActive:!1,discountPrice:9},{name:'doom',price:5,discountActive:!0,discountPrice:4},{name:'mk',price:15,discountActive:!1,discountPrice:11},{name:'aoe',price:20,discountActive:!0,discountPrice:10}];
 
const value = o => o.discountActive ? o.discountPrice : o.price;

games.sort((a, b) => value(a) - value(b))

console.log(games)
```